# Why no MVC methodology for desktop applications?

Tags: .net, mvc

I'm currently learning how to develop web apps with C#, ASP, .NET and MVC. I am enjoying the MVC paradigm a lot, but then thought about using this to develop desktop software with. I googled around, but found nothing using the MVC pattern to create desktop apps that connect to databases. So what software pattern do .net programmers like use if they not using MVC?

Thanks.

Comment: You have mvp for Winforms and mvvm for wpf

Comment: Right.  What @James said.  Windows Presentation Foundation uses Model-View-View Model (MVVM), and there are libraries available for implementing Model-View-Presenter in Winforms.  Model-View-Controller is a better fit for web applications.

Comment: I think the *general idea* of MVC was applied to desktop applications before web applications were much more than simple CGI scripts...

Comment: MVC [originated in Smalltalk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller#History), IIRC.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yes, and it was already superseded there before the Web was even invented.

Comment: This is just a clarification, as the question is clearly targeting .NET, however it might be relevant to mention that the Cocoa frameworks for OSX and iOS development both use MVC.  So there is a lot of desktop software using the MVC pattern, though I can't tell you exactly when it was first adopted on that platform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try looking for MVVM instead of MVC.

Here's an [MS article on MVVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) which is very much applicable to [WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms754130.aspx)

And here's [another tutorial on MVVM with WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial)

Or look at [MVP with winforms](http://winformsmvp.codeplex.com/).

From a broad point of view, MVVM and MVP are just variants of MVC.